# Icon on hover in ChakraUI Button component custom theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I am currently building a component library for a project following given design specifications and therefore am extending the default button theme in a separate `button.ts` which contains something like this:

```js
const solid: SystemStyleFunction = (props) => ({
  bg: mode("tealLight", "teal")(props),
  color: "bgDark",
  borderRadius: "20px",
  _active: {
    bg: mode("white", "bgDark")(props),
    color: mode("bgDark", "white")(props)
  },
  _disabled: {
    bg: "lightGrey",
    color: "grey"
  }
});

const Button : StyleConfig = {
  defaultProps: {
    size: "md"
  },
  variants: {
    solid: solid,
  }
};

export default Button;
```

Works like a charm so far.

**Now the given design requires that an arrow is to be shown on hover to the right of the button's label.**

Back in the days of hand-written (S)CSS, i would have just added a pseudo-element only visible on `:hover` – here, of course, i am now looking into adding `_hover: { ... }` to the above `SystemStyleFunction`-config.

According to the [Chakra UI docs, showing an icon](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/form/button?scroll=true#button-with-icon) on a standard form button can easily be achieved via the `rightIcon` or `leftIcon` prop. I do have the icon component ready at hand, however:

> The `leftIcon` and `rightIcon` prop values *should* be react elements NOT strings.

So how can the hover-only icon be achieved then ...

- can i use `React.createElement(...)` to define the element right there (or in the `StyleConfig` object at the end of my file)?
- can i convert my `button.ts` into a `button.tsx` and then add the icon-element in JSX-style syntax?
- is there an alternative way of setting the icon element (because the documentation says "*should*", not "*must*")
- or is this impossible to be done with my styled `<Button>` and a completely different approach is needed (if so, kindly advise)?

Comment: Hey, why do you want to add the arrow as a string? you don't have an svg design for it?

Comment: @EkkoKo I do have an SVG file representing the arrow at hand, ready wrapped in a react element. I'm asking how to add that to my existing `Button`-component theme as described above, for instance via the `rightIcon`-prop, or any other viable approach.

Answer (score 0):

I did this way :

```
<InputGroup
       alignItems="center"
       bgColor="#e27065"
       w={200}
       borderRadius="3"
       _hover={{ bg: "white", svg: { fill: "black" } }}
     >
       <InputLeftElement
         children={<BsSearch color="white" />}
         height={8}
         boxSize={7}
         alignItems="center"
         padding={1}
       />
       <Input
         type="text"
         placeholder="Search"
         _placeholder={{ color: "white" }}
         _hover={{ _placeholder: { color: "black" } }}
         height={7}
         borderRadius="3"
       />
     </InputGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm sure this works – and at the end of the day we also solved it in JSX in a similar fashion. However this does not answer the question how to achieve the same via a [custom theme file](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#customizing-single-components)